# Does the closure of a nontrivial connected set in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ necessarily contain an arc?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Let $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{n}$ be a nontrivial (not a singleton or $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ itself) connected set. Must the closure of $X$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ contain an arc?

Very "nasty" connected sets such as the Knaster-Kuratowski fan that I have seen all have arcs upon closure in Euclidean space. Is there a connected subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ that does not have an arc upon closure?

I suspect that a counterexample may exist in continuum theory. That is, there may be Euclidean continuum containing no arc, but I am not well versed in the subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pseudo-arc (or any other hereditarily indecomposable continuum) is a compact space embeddable in $\Bbb R^2$ which is connected but totally path-disconnected.

More surprisingly there are even *hereditarily decomponsable* continua with this property, see Exercise 2.27 in Nadler's *Continuum Theory* for an example.

Comment: I knew it'd be a continuum! Thank you.